# Python/Selenium Click on an element in a ul

Tags: python, selenium

I am new to Python/Selenium (< 3 days). I am trying to click on the "grades" item of an unordered list (Please see image). I have tried find_element_by_link_text, find_element_by_css_selector but am unable to find it.

Image from inspect element

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the HTML as text instead of an image. That image is unreadable. Also, post the code you have tried and the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the HTML it is pretty clear that the desired field is within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"frameDetail")))
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a#grades")))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"frameDetail")))
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@id='grades']")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)

Comment: @Student I am glad that I was able to help you. Please upvote the answer if it was useful to you. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks again. I did upvote the answer. It seems to stay at 0 though.

Comment: @Student Thanks.