# Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, webdriver

How would I switch to this iframe in selenium knowing only

```
<iframe name="Dialogue Window">
```

Answer (score 114):

You can use an XPath to locate the `<iframe>`:

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@name='Dialogue Window']")
```

Then `switch_to` the `<iframe>`:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

---

Here's how to switch back to the default content (out of the `<iframe>`):

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: Good general solution, especially if the iframe has to be targeted by something other than a `name` - which is really the only way that [the selenium docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#moving-between-windows-and-frames) specify transitioning

Comment: Works perfectly at last! After I have been researching a lot about why I can't find certain elements in the browser. I have been getting NoSuchElementException error before. I didn't realise that I need to switch to another iframe. Thanks!

Comment: `driver.switch_to.default_content()` also work in cases where you click action and are forwarded to another host.

Answer (score 35):

As per the HTML of the `<iframe>` element, it has the *name* attribute set as *Dialogue Window*. So to switch within the `<iframe>` you need to use the [`switch_to()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to) method and you can use either of the following approaches:

- Using the *name* attribute of the `<iframe>` node as follows:

  ```
  # driver.switch_to.frame(‘frame_name’)
  driver.switch_to.frame("Dialogue Window")
  ```
- Using the `<iframe>` [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) identified through *name* attribute as follows:

  ```
  driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_name('Dialogue Window'))
  ```
- Using the `<iframe>` [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) identified through [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors) as follows:

  ```
  driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("iframe[name='Dialogue Window']"))
  ```
- Using the `<iframe>` [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) identified through [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) as follows:

  ```
  driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@name='Dialogue Window']"))
  ```

---

Ideally, you should induce [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) inconjunction with [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) as *`frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it()`* for the desired *frame* as follows:

- Using *NAME*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME,"Dialogue Window")))
  ```
- Using [*CSS_SELECTOR*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48578370/7429447):

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[name='Dialogue Window']")))
  ```
- Using [XPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50882166/7429447):

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@name='Dialogue Window']")))
  ```

---

### Switching back from frame

- To switch back to the *Parent Frame* you can use the following line of code:

  ```
  driver.switch_to.parent_frame()
  ```
- To switch back to the *Top Level Browsing Context* / *Top Window* you can use the following line of code:

  ```
  driver.switch_to.default_content()
  ```

---

### tl; dr

[Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447)

Comment: Thanks for the "Switching back from frame" part.

Answer (score -3):

I have resolved this issue in Python-Selenium. Please use the below code:

```py
srtHandle = driver.window_handles
driver.switch_to_window(srtHandle[0])
```

Then switch to the frame in which the element is located.